# How to build a mobile app for multiple clients from the same codebase

Tags: android, ios

We have an iOS app and an Android app that we customize for two separate clients. And it's too cumbersome to edit the code when we build for a client.

Is there a way to automate this so that we can just keep maintaining the common codebase and have the client-specific ones in different files? The customizations are quite trivial (e.g. name of the app, backend server address, some strings, etc.)

I'm a web dev not a mobile dev. In Python/Django, I simply put the client-specific constants and variables in separate `settings.py` files and then choose which file to use upon deploy. This makes it easy for me to maintain the server app for different clients.

I'm wondering if there's something similar that we can do for iOS and Android projects.

Comment: You can write settings as constants in a text file or SQLite DB and read from there for both the apps.

Comment: Isn't this a perfect use-case for preprocessor directives?

Answer (score 3):

For android there's a fairly straightforward method which is a built in feature: build flavors.

You'd specify an additional flavor for one of the clients and keep the main flavor for the other client.

Then add copies of the files that need modification in the corresponding folder of the flavor.
Here is a thorough description of flavors and how to do it for your specific requirement:
http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/

Android's documentation on build flavors: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors

Answer (score 0):

For iOS I would use pre-processor commands to call different code for different clients. I would also write a script (I wrote mine in swift to run in Terminal on the Mac) that will take in settings and make changes to .plist files and project files depending on parameters you give the script

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in the same environment and faced the same problem . Follow the below procedure and it should work like a charm : 
Step 1  . Create a Package and declare it as a library . 
Step 2. . Create a module and declare the above library in dependencies .
Step 3. Create another module and declare library as a dependency .

Now you library code is the base code for both modules . Whichever are the client specific changes you want to perform can be performed in modules .